# On the operation of sort()

Tags: sorting

I would like to understand the workings of sort, in particular:

```css
>>> a=[2,4,5,1]
>>> a
[2, 4, 5, 1]
>>> b=a
>>> b
[2, 4, 5, 1]
>>> b.sort()
>>> b
[1, 2, 4, 5]
>>> a
[1, 2, 4, 5]
```

Why when I apply sort() to the list "b" copied from "a", sort() also changes the list "a"?

Comment: add a language tag please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

typeof a "object"
typeof b "object"

In Javascript "object" is passed by reference.

So a and b are referring to same object. So sorting on "a" will have same effect on "b".

Answer (score 1):

You don't state what programming environment we're talking about. My best guess: `b` is a reference to `a`, so sorting `b` basically means that `a` is sorted implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've just resolve by my self...

```css
>>> a=[2,4,5,1]
>>> b=a[:]
>>> b
[2, 4, 5, 1]
>>> b.sort()
>>> b
[1, 2, 4, 5]
>>> a
[2, 4, 5, 1]
```

Thanks